# Are files in the documents folder automatically overwritten?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4

If I have a file abc.png in the documents folder and then download another file also named abc.png to that folder will it automatically overwrite the older version or append a suffix to the newly downloaded file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be overwritten, with no error or warning.